# Convert double decimal to Hex, Binary and Octal strings

Tags: objective-c, math

Is there a custom or standard library that I can use with objective c to convert a decimal floating point value into Hexadecimal, Binary and Octal NSStrings?

I've been looking around a lot but can only find how to convert the other direction (from everything else into decimal), by using: `double result = (double)strtoll(myHexString.UTF8String, NULL,16)`

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal floating point"??

Comment: Probably the same question as Hot Licks, but what encoding are you expecting when a floating point number is printed as e.g. hexadecimal? Are you expecting it to be in IEEE 754?

Comment: I want to be able to convert any double decimal (with decimal points and negatives) to Octal, Hex and Binary. Similar to what this online tool does: http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

Comment: FYI, standard doubles are *not* decimal numbers.

Comment: "double", in Objective-C, is a floating-point number -- not an integer.  It really only makes sense to convert integers into octal/hex/binary, unless you simply want to see the (unintelligible) bits inside the number.

Answer (score 1):

As for octal and hex, you can exploit the fact that you can format numbers in hex and octal using the %x and %o specifiers:

```
NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hex: %x Octal: %o",14,14];
```

But this only for the integral part, so you can use integers.If you want also the decimal part, to obtain fixed points you need to implement the algorithm, same for binary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complement the previous answer, the format specifier %x allows to treat integer value only.
If you get a decimal value greater than the max integer value you can use long long to cast your double value by this way: `NSString * hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llx", (long long)doubleValue];`