# Convert decimal NSString to a hex string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I need to convert `NSString`s denoting decimal values to hex strings, e.g. a string with value "10" should be converted to string "A", "15" should be converted to "E", "20" should be "14" and so on.

How do I do that?

Comment: You should read about the format specifier used when printing formatted values as a NSString: [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). Similar format specifiers apply to `printf` and friends. Now, you just need to figure how to get an integer from a string, then print the number with the corresponding format specifiers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert double decimal to Hex, Binary and Octal strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202964/convert-double-decimal-to-hex-binary-and-octal-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSString *hexedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X",[originalString intValue]];
```

Note that you might want to do some (non)sense checking.

Comment: Aaaarrrhhhh - Of course!  Stupid me. Had to most of it earlier, I just forgot the intValue method. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You should take care while using it though - make sure there are no possibilities of garbage input strings.

Comment: Clearly Yes. Validations has been taken care of before the conversion.